# How to pass string containing apostrophe characters using Android WebView.evaluatejavascript API to be displayed in Webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

How can I pass string containing apostrophe characters from my Android activity  using Android WebView.evaluatejavascript API that needs string to be displayed in webpage using Webview?

I have tried string containing apostrophe character with \ :

> "What is App\'s name?"

This way string displays fine when displayed within Android Activity.
Also string displays fine when using directly this inside javascript code of webpage to be displayed by WebView.

But when the same string is passed from my Android activity to Javascript of webpage using  WebView.evaluatejavascript API then I get runtime error:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Reason to pass such string using WebView.evaluatejavascript API is that I want to manage string translations within Android code and pass them to Javascript to be updated in webpage shown by WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by replacing each apostrophe character in Android string   by [image: ampersand-quot-semicolon] and passed modified string to WebView.evaluatejavascript API.

Then in JS code that handles API, I replaced each [image: ampersand-quot-semicolon] back to apostrophe character which webview displayed it without issue.

Hope this helps other people as well;